# Alfresco WCM Sandbox -Not able to delete files

Tags: java, alfresco, sandbox, wcm

We are using alfresco 4.0 enterprise edition and installed WCM for the same. Using WCM web-form we are generating some dump items in JSON. All the things are working properly in that but in some cases when I am deleting any of dump file or JSON files some times its not getting deleted and stays at that place permanently. Below I have attached screen shot for more details.

[image]

Can any one please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe starting on 4.0 Alfresco started keeping the delete files until they got actually deleted from the repository, if you use share you can see there's a trash can where all the files are stored and until it is emptied the files get deleted, if you are not using share for what I see you can review the [Alfresco documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/tuh-options-removeitems.html) you might find it useful